# how to add "," between 2 element in groupby aggretation

Tags: pandas

Hellow everyone,

Me again, I did the groupby function in pandas , result as my photo below:

[image]

The question is how to insert "," between each element in method column, sth like in year 1998 , method column will be "Radial Velocity, Radial Velocity, ..."
and the second question is how i can remove duplicate in each row of method columns?

every assist will be appriciated!!

the csv for this lab here [dataframe for this lab][2]

updated:
update my dataframe for this example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

mydict = {'year':[1991,1992,1993,1994,1995],
          'distance_min' : [40.57,25.2,18.3,21.4,36],
          'distance_max' : [82.1,50.3,32.2,57.3,42],
          'method_sum' : ['Pulsar TimingPulsar Timing','Radial VelocityRadial VelocityRadial','Pulsar TimingPulsar Timing','Radial VelocityRadial VelocityRadial','Pulsar TimingPulsar TimingRadial VelocityRadialVelocityRadia'] 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a minimal sample of data as text (ideally dataframe constructor) and the matching expected output

Comment: @mozway hi Bro, I have updated the data file in the question. Could you please help assist ?

Comment: Please read the help on how to ask. I don't want to download a file from google drive when you could make the effort to write a clean question with a **sample** of the data, that can be **easily** copy pasted and having the **expected output**.

Comment: @mozway thank you , I have updated the question with simple code to create the DF.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by each element those who are seperated by a white space, then the solution is clear by using `df['method_sum']=df['method_sum'].str.replace(' ',', ')`

the final code will be:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

mydict = {'year':[1991,1992,1993,1994,1995],
          'distance_min' : [40.57,25.2,18.3,21.4,36],
          'distance_max' : [82.1,50.3,32.2,57.3,42],
          'method_sum' : ['Pulsar TimingPulsar Timing','Radial VelocityRadial VelocityRadial','Pulsar TimingPulsar Timing','Radial VelocityRadial VelocityRadial','Pulsar TimingPulsar TimingRadial VelocityRadialVelocityRadia'] 
}
df= pd.DataFrame(mydict)
df['method_sum']=df['method_sum'].str.replace(' ',', ')
```

you need to make sure to clean your data before grouping and aggregating, this is how the flow of work move.